# resultSet iterating through rows within the same line

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

Ok that may not make much sense so I'll try and clarify with code, I've got a basic Result set like so: -

```
ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery(constants.execQueueSQL());
```

I then want to iterate through this with a while loop like so: -

```
while (results.next()){
    String val1 = results.getString("col 1");
    String val2 =  results.getString("col 2");
    String val3 = results.getString("col 3");
}
```

Now, when I debug this within eclipse I can see that before executing the while line the currentRow is already showing as 1 in `results`, and as I step to each line within the while the currentRow count increases by 1!!

I know that I have 4 rows returned but by the time I get to retrieving col 3 I'm already out, and all subsequent values are wrong as they are being obtained from separate lines, why is this...?

Comment: Do you have a watch expression within Eclipse which is calling `next()` by any chance?

Comment: Well you should be able to see which expressions you're watching in the debugger window. Does it work if you're not debugging?

Comment: I'll give it a try, I suppose I can just stick a breakpoint in a and run to that point and see if the values are right...

Comment: I'd suggest just adding logging for each iteration of the loop after fetching the values.

Comment: Try calling results.first() and use a foot based while instead.

Comment: @Hannes, wha?  Whats a foot based while?

Comment: And you are absolutely sure that `results.next()` is not invoked before the `while` loop?

Comment: @MorkPork `do { ... } while(results.next());`

Comment: @Peter I was under the impression that when results are returned it always starts before the first entry, so the first next then puts it onto the first line...?  There are no other results.next() lines in my code before this.

Comment: @Hannes I'll give this a try when I get a chance to revisit it, thanks :)